# How do I fix Seek Command making song go back to beginning - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Seek command with YTDL-Core and Discord.js as part of my updated music commands and I am having issues with how I am seeking the song playing in the Voice Call.

What my seek command should exactly do is if I specify `n!seek 2:00` for example, it should go to `2:00` timestamp from where the song is currently played to that specified timestamp.

Instead of that, the issue I am getting is if I specify any song timestamp (2:00 etc.) it will go back to the beginning of when the song is played, `0:00`. There are no errors in the Console that I am aware of when I execute the command.

Seek.js: (Command used to seek song)

```js
//Problem is seek will keep going back to start of song whenever it does.

const {handleVideo, queue, youtube}= require('../../util/music/handleVideo');
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(msg.guild.id);
  if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send("Join voice channel first");
  if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send("No songs to seek");
  if (serverQueue.voiceChannel.id !== msg.member.voiceChannel.id) return msg.chanel.send(`You must in **${serverQueue.voiceChannel.name}** to seek the song`);
  try {
    const curDuration = (serverQueue.songs[0].durationm * 60000) + ((serverQueue.songs[0].durations % 60000) * 1000);
    const choiceDur = args.join(" ").split(":");
    if (choiceDur.length < 2) return msg.channel.send("No duration provided or invalid ?");
    const optDurr = (parseInt(choiceDur[0], 10) * 60000) + ((parseInt(choiceDur[1], 10) % 60000) * 1000);
    if (optDurr > curDuration) return msg.channel.send("Your duration is too big");
    serverQueue.songs.splice(1, 0, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
  } catch (e) {
    return msg.channel.send(`Oh no an error occured :( \`${e.message}\` try again later`);
  }
};

exports.conf = {
  aliases: [],
  clientPerm: "",
  authorPerm: ""
};

exports.help = {
  name: "seek",
  description: "Seek current songs",
  usage: "seek <duration>",
  example: ["seek 00:00"]
};
```

handleVideo.js: (How the music commands are handled)

```js
const YouTube = require('simple-youtube-api');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const moment = require("moment");
let config = require('../../config.json');
const youtube = new YouTube(config.youtube_api);
const { Client, Util, RichEmbed} = require('discord.js');
var queue = new Map();
async function handleVideo(video, msg, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
    if (video.durationSeconds === 0) {
            let livestreamembed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Music **`)
            .setDescription(`**Cannot play Livestreams...** ❌\n\nPlease use YouTube Links only instead.`)
            .setColor(`#e05e7c`)
            return msg.channel.send(livestreamembed);

            return undefined;
        }
    const serverQueue = queue.get(msg.guild.id);
    //console.log(video)
    const song = {
    id: video.id,
    title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
    url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`, 
    durationmm: video.durationSeconds ? video.durationSeconds : video.duration / 1000,
    channel: msg.member.voiceChannel.name,
    uploadedby: video.channel.title, 
    channelurl: `https://www.youtube.com/channel/${video.channel.id}`,
    author: msg.author,
    durationh: video.duration.hours,
    durationm: video.duration.minutes,
    durations: video.duration.seconds, 
    duration: video.duration,
};
    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueConstruct = {
            textChannel: msg.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 100,
            playing: true,
            loop: false, 
        };
        queue.set(msg.guild.id, queueConstruct);
        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();

            queueConstruct.connection = connection;
            play(msg.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0])
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`NateBot » Cannot join Voice Channel: ${error}`);
            queue.delete(msg.guild.id);
      return msg.channel.send(`**NateBot |** Could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
        }
    } else {
        if (serverQueue.songs.some(song => song.id === video.id)) {             
        msg.channel.send(`**NateBot |** **Error Queuing this song...**\n\n**\`${Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title)}\`** is already queued/playing!\nCheck \`n!queue\` for Music Queue`);
        return;
    }
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        if (playlist) return undefined;

//Queue Message (Sent When song is requested 2nd time or more)
var queueembed = new RichEmbed() 
    .setTitle(`**Music **`)
    .setColor(`#0xd677ff`)
    .setDescription(`
__**Successfully Queued!**__ 
**[${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id}})**

**Uploaded by »** **[${song.uploadedby}](${song.channelurl})**
**Video ID »** ${song.id}
**Duration »** **\`${require('../../util/util.js').timeString(song.durationmm)}\`**
**Published »** ${moment.utc(song.publishedAt).format('LLLL')}
`)
  .setFooter(`Requested by » ${song.author.username}`, `${song.author.displayAvatarURL}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setImage(`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${song.id}/maxresdefault.jpg`)

 return msg.channel.send(queueembed);
    }
    return undefined;
}

function play(guild, song, msg) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url, { quality: 'highestaudio', filter: "audioonly", highWaterMark: 2000 }))
        .on('end', reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.') console.log('NateBot » Song ended.');
            else console.log(reason);
            const shifed = serverQueue.songs.shift();
      if(serverQueue.loop) serverQueue.songs.push(shifed);
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 100);

//Now Playing Embed (Sent when Bot starts playing music)
var pleyembed = new RichEmbed() 
    .setTitle(`**Music **`)
    .setColor(`0x76d6ff`)
    .setDescription(`
__**Now Playing!**__ 
**[${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id}})**

**Uploaded by »** **[${song.uploadedby}](${song.channelurl})**
**Video ID »** ${song.id}
**Duration »** **\`${require('../../util/util.js').timeString(song.durationmm)}\`**
**Published »** ${moment.utc(song.publishedAt).format('LLLL')}
`)
  .setImage(`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${song.id}/maxresdefault.jpg`)


    serverQueue.textChannel.send(pleyembed);

}
module.exports = {handleVideo, queue, youtube};
```

What i've tried to do is to change the following in seek.js

```js
    return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
```

to

```js
    return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.seek()
```

As this was noted in https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StreamOptions, I tried to do this method but to no avail...

I am not 100% sure why this is causing the issue. Perhaps its probably a discord.js version change. I currently use `11.5.1` as Discord.JS version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to seek to a point in a song with discord.js music bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750089/how-to-seek-to-a-point-in-a-song-with-discord-js-music-bot)