# How to seek to a point in a song with discord.js music bot?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

I am trying to make a `discord.js` music bot with `ytdl-core`. I am not quite sure how to seek to a current time in a song when using a command, and searching for help hasn't really done much. The command would work like `!seek 1:30`.

What I am looking to find out is either:
a) Does the dispatcher include a seek function?

```js
//i.e like below
let ms = 90000; //would be converted from arguments
queue.connection.dispatcher.seek(ms) //Does this exist???
```

or b) How can I start a song at a certain time?

```js
//Add the song again, but with a timestamp, and end current song
let seekedSong = queue.songs[0];
seekedSong.startTime = 90000; 
queue.songs.unshift(seekedSong);
queue.connection.dispatcher.end()
/* However, how do I start a song given a start time?
 * 
 * In my play.js file, which plays the next song in the queue automatically, 
 * how can i tell it to start at a time? I tried dispatcher.end() and supplying 
 * a youtube link with ?t={sec}s, but that didnt work
 */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Discord.js v12

[`VoiceConnection#play`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play) takes a second [`StreamOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/StreamOptions) argument. You can specify how many seconds you want to seek with the `seek` property:

```js
// When playing the song:
const stream = ytdl('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
// Store the stream somewhere
queue.currentSong = stream

// When seeking:
queue.connection.play(queue.currentSong, {seek: ms / 1000})
```

Comment: And how is it in Discord.js v13?

Comment: @dperales555 There doesn’t seem to be a simple way of doing it yet. There was [this PR](https://github.com/discordjs/voice/pull/198) that would allow you to do this, but the discordjs/voice repo was archived in favour of the discordjs/discordjs  monorepo. You could use ffmpeg to seek the song before passing it into `connection.play`. I might add it to this answer when I get around to it.

Comment: thanks! I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 3):

## **Discord.js V13**

You can use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) like that :

```js
const fluentFfmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
let ms = 90000;

let song = ytdl('some youtube link', {quality: 'highestaudio'})

let editedSong = fluentFfmpeg({source: song}).toFormat('mp3').setStartTime(Math.ceil(ms/1000)) // set the song start time

queue.play(editedSong)
```

Comment: @dperales555 does this respond to your answer ?

Comment: What is `ytdl` in this case?

Comment: const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

Comment: I spent way too long trying various solutions around the web, but I found this and it worked! Thank you so much!